# Vim slow over UNC paths

Tags: vim, unc

I am experiencing some very painful lag when accessing directories/files over UNC paths using gVim 7.3 on Windows Vista.

It is slow reading/writing files, as well as tab completiong of directory/file names when opening new buffers. I don't notice this lag when using WordPad though.

Things I've tried:

- Cream (apparently they had a fix for directory naming schemes)
- Mapping the network drive to z: or something else
- Various settings

  - set ffs=dos
  - set complete=.,w,b,u,t
  - set noshellslash

I've tried cygwin, but the same noticeable lag appears there as well. I already have all swap/backup files turned off. Any help greatly appreciated... I've dumped my vimrc for reference

```
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif

set nocompatible

:runtime! ftplugin/man.vim

set backspace=indent,eol,start

colorscheme torte " murphy
syn on

set ffs=unix,dos

" portable friendly
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile
set viminfo=
" gui options (http://steveno.wordpress.com/2007/10/08/vim-for-windows/)
set guioptions-=T  " No toolbar
set gfn=Consolas:h9:cANSI

set history=50
set ruler
set showcmd
set incsearch
set number
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set wrap
set wildmode=longest,list,full  " Complete longest string, list alternatives
                                " then completed next full match, cycling back

function! ToggleHLSearch()
    if &hls
        set nohls
    else
        set hls
    endif
endfunction

function! InsertTabWrapper()
    let col = col('.') - 1
    if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
        return "\<tab>"
    else
        return "\<c-p>"
    endif
endfunction


inoremap <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<CR>
nmap <silent> <C-n> <Esc>:call ToggleHLSearch()<CR>
nmap ,s :source ~/.vimrc<Return>
" change current directory to that of open buffer
nmap ,c :cd %:p:h<Return>
nmap <c-h> <c-w>h<c-w><bar>
nmap <c-l> <c-w>l<c-w><bar>
map <C-J> <C-W>j<C-W>_
map <C-K> <C-W>k<C-W>_
map Q gq

" Commenting blocks of text
" ,<    <!-- --> html style comments
map ,< :s/^\(.*\)$/<!-- \1 -->/<CR><Esc>:nohlsearch<CR>
" ,/     // comments
map ,/ :s/^/\/\//<CR>
" ,#    # comments
map ,# :s/^/#/<CR>
" uncommenting all of the above
"map ,- :s/^\(\/\/|<!-- |#\)\(.*\)\(-->\)*/\1/<CR>

if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

if has("autocmd")
    "&& !exists("autocommands_loaded")
  let autocommands_loaded = 1
  filetype plugin indent on
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!
  " Remove ALL autocommands for the current group.
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal g`\"" |
    \ endif
  au BufRead *.html set filetype=html4
  augroup END

  " allow editing Word Docs sanely
  autocmd BufReadPre *.doc set ro
  autocmd BufReadPre *.doc set hlsearch!
  autocmd BufReadPost *.doc %!antiword "%"

  " uncomment the following to remember the view of the file edited between
  " sessions
  " au BufWinLeave * mkview
  " au BufWinEnter * silent loadview

  " run file with PHP CLI (CTRL-M)
  autocmd FileType php noremap <C-M> :w!<CR>:!/usr/bin/php %<CR>
  " parser check (CTRL-L)
  autocmd FileType php noremap <C-L> :!/usr/bin/php -l %<CR>

  " highlight current line only for current buffer
  "autocmd BufLeave * setlocal nocursorline
  "autocmd BufEnter * setlocal cursorline

  au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tea set filetype=tea
  "au! Syntax newlang source $VIM/newlanguage.vim

else
  set autoindent

endif
```

Answer (score 1):

the same thing was driving me insane, but there is a fix I just found.
I really do not know why yet, but the problem goes away when you disable plugin/matchparen.vim plugin (changing vim extension would do the trick).
I will definitely look into it as I use parentheses matching a lot.

Comment: after playing with the code, I have to say there is nothing I can do to speed it up... even if the matching function is empty, it remains slow, and just disabling autocmd line solves the problem. so it seems to be a problem burned deeper than in the plugin code itself... disable & enjoy the speed

Answer (score 1):

See

```
:he swap-file
```

You can disable swapfiles with `:se noswapfile` (caution!) or use the `` `directory` `` setting to keep the swapfile on a local disk.

Starting vim with the `-n` option also disables swapfiles; you might want to combine that with `-R` for readonly mode

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I found is that mounting a UNC path as a local drive letter and let Vim use the drive-letter based paths only.
e.g., `\\some-server\path\to\workdir` => `Z:\path\to\workdir`

This eliminates the lag completely unless you have connection problems.